# All Anko references are undefined

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I am completely new to android developement, so I just installed Android studio a few days ago.
I created a new project with Kotlin support and an empty activity, and want to use the anko library to create a dialog.

My MainActivity.kt looks like this:

```
package me.example.com.test

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        b_test.setOnClickListener {
            makeDialog().show()
        }
    }
}
```

and I created a test_dialog.kt with the following contents:

```
package me.example.com.test

import org.jetbrains.anko.*

fun makeDialog() = alert("Test"){
    yesButton { toast("Oh…") }
    noButton {}
}
```

and to the build.gradle for the app I added the anko stuff:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:$anko_version"

// Anko Layouts
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk27:$anko_version" // sdk15, sdk19, sdk21, sdk23 are also available
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-appcompat-v7:$anko_version"

// Coroutine listeners for Anko Layouts
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk27-coroutines:$anko_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-appcompat-v7-coroutines:$anko_version"

// Anko SQLite
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sqlite:$anko_version"
```

When I first copy pasted it from their GitHub it was sdk25. I replaced it with 27 (since that was the chosen api on project creation).

And to the build.gradle for the project I added:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.0'
ext.anko_version='0.10.8'
```

Both versions have the same problem: alert, yesButton, noButton and toast in the test_dialog.kt are unresolved references.

The Kotlin version was originally different, but there was a warning (additionally to the unresolved references errors) saying something about mismatched Kotlin versions, so I changed that.

Does anyone know how to solve these unresolved references?

Comment: Use sdk version for Anko that is lower than your minSdk

Comment: My minSDKVersion is 23, I tried version 21 22 and 23 for anko. Still the same problem.

Comment: Well I guess the best thing you can do is remove anko as is and just write your own wrapper over AlertDialog.Builder :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your methods are unresolved because `alert` is an extension method implemented on top of some kind of context. Available methods are `Context.alert` `Fragment.alert` and `AnkoContext.alert`. So if you want to wrap your alert dialog in another method, it must also extend one of these three classes.

So your `makeDialog` function should look something like this:

```
fun Context.makeDialog() = alert("Test") {
    yesButton { toast("oh..") }
    noButton { }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Didn't expect an answer anymore :D